# Assign a key to each object

Tags: javascript, json, casperjs

The following code snippet is extracting data from a webpage.

```
  jsonObj = {};
  jsonObj.title = this.fetchText('a.profile-full-name');

  jsonObj.services = this.getHTML('div.info-list-text span:nth-child(2) span');
  jsonObj.services = jsonObj.services.replace(/&amp;/g,"and");  

  jsonObj.location = this.getHTML('div.pro-info-horizontal-list div.info-list-label:nth-child(3) div.info-list-text span');
  jsonObj.contact = this.fetchText('span.pro-contact-text');
  jsonObj.description = this.getHTML('div.profile-about div:nth-child(1)');  
  //jsonObj.description.replace(/\s/g, '');   

  //require('utils').dump(jsonObj);
  jsonObj.description = jsonObj.description.replace(/[\t\n]/g,"");   

  //jsonObj = JSON.stringify(jsonObj, null, '\t');
  require('utils').dump(jsonObj);
```

Its output is,

```
{
    "title": "Marcelle Guilbeau, Interior Designer",
    "services": "Interior Designers &amp; Decorators",
    "location": "5007 Wyoming Ave.",
    "description": "Marcelle takes her clients on a journey, drawing out their needs to create an oasis that reflects their personal sense of style and renews their connection."
}
{
    "title": "Eric Ross Interiors, LLC",
    "services": "Interior Designers &amp; Decorators",
    "location": "220 Lewisburg Avenue",
    "description": "Eric Ross Interiors exists to create beautiful interiors and a luxury design experience for its clients.  We are committed to creating whole room environments for our clients in Nashville, Middle Tennessee and Beyond.  Our job is to listen to you about the look and feel you want to achieve.  We want to make you comfortable  Houzz 2013, 2014, 2015 Outstanding Customer Service and 2015 Best of Design"
}
```

Is there a way to assign a key to each of the above objects. For example,

```
   "data1": {
        "title": "Marcelle Guilbeau, Interior Designer",
        "services": "Interior Designers &amp; Decorators",
        "location": "5007 Wyoming Ave.",
        "description": "Marcelle takes her clients on a journey, drawing out their needs to create an oasis that reflects their personal sense of style and renews their connection."
    }
    "data2" :{
        "title": "Eric Ross Interiors, LLC",
        "services": "Interior Designers &amp; Decorators",
        "location": "220 Lewisburg Avenue",
        "description": "Eric Ross Interiors exists to create beautiful interiors and a luxury design experience for its clients.  We are committed to creating whole room environments for our clients in Nashville, Middle Tennessee and Beyond.  Our job is to listen to you about the look and feel you want to achieve.  We want to make you comfortable  Houzz 2013, 2014, 2015 Outstanding Customer Service and 2015 Best of Design"
    }
```

My final goal is to convert these individual objects into json data. I have tried using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create JSON code with Javascript you should try something like

```
var someObjectWhichHappensToBeAstring = "user";    
var data = {name:someObjectWhichHappensToBeAstring, message:"hello"};
var JSON = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Which can be nested as much as you want.
So in your case, if jsonObject is already a json object you can simply do this:

```
var data = {data1:jsonObj1, data2:jsonObj2};
var JSON = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: `jsonObj` is not a JSON object. It is an object with several different objects in it.

Comment: That shouldn't matter for modern browsers. For older browsers (like IE6), you can include https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js for compatibility.